# Google Editable Sheet hide column row headers in an iframe

Tags: iframe

Does anyone know how to hide G sheet column and row headings in iframe?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwl2l.png)

The following syntax did not work
chrome = false
widget = false